# Nested sort with different sort order by parameter in Tableau

Tags: sorting, parameters, tableau-desktop, nested-sortable

Good afternoon. My problem is this:

There are 3 levels of dimension hierarchy in the table that can be collapsed and expanded. Each of them should be sorted depending on the selected parameter, which simultaneously determines the type of dimension [dimension formula example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvMur.png) and the sort order.
The idea is that when one of the parameters set to time line, this dimension should be sorted by months, otherwise - by the measure.

In order for the sorting to happen correctly, I created fields for sorting corresponding to each parameter [sort field formula example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOU3q.png) and sorted by field for each dimension [sort by field parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO7Wc.png). This works well, except that sorting does not always correct at the second and third levels of dimensions like here: [example of incorrect sorting from internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEgfq.png).
As a solution of the problem I tried to use nested sorting, but I ran into another problem - when collapsing and expanding the hierarchy, the sort settings for the second and third level were reset to the first level settings. [before collapsing and expanding the hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZB2P.png) - [after collapsing and expanding the hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWdEV.png)

Here is a [minimal reproducible example](https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/igor2629/viz/NestedsortwithdifferentsortorderbyparameterMinimalReproducibleExample/NestedsortingwithParameters?publish=yes) of my problem, you can download workbook to inspect the situation.

Please help me resolve this problems or find a way where I can find a solution.

Comment: Is there any way you can make a [mcve] maybe simplified to two sorts? Otherwise I can only offer vague advice, like make sure you use a "stable sort" if you're re-sorting according to a different parameter (and expecting ties to be resolved by the previous sort).

Comment: Thank you for attention, here you can fined specially developed  example: https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/igor2629/viz/NestedsortwithdifferentsortorderbyparameterMinimalReproducibleExample/NestedsortingwithParameters?publish=yes